# How to calculate the argument and its limit for the sequence $z_n=-2+i\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, limits, polar-coordinates

I am trying to show that the limit of the sequence
$$z_n=-2+i\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}$$
exists, using the polar representation. Note that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }z_n=-2$. $$$$I am finding difficulty in arriving at the final answer (specifically in finding the limit of the argument - I am getting a wrong result)

---

**In polar form:**
$$ r=\sqrt{4+\frac{1}{n^4}}$$
$$\theta_0 =tan^{-1}(\frac{(-1)^n}{-2n^2})=-tan^{-1}(\frac{(-1)^n}{2n^2})$$

where $\theta_0$ is the principal argument defined on $-\pi <\theta _0\le \pi $.

Now taking the limit of the modulus, we get
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }r=\sqrt{4+0}=2$$
and for the argument, we consider even and odd integers:

- *If n is even:*

[image]

- *If n is odd:*

[image]

**But in the text book, the answers are**

[image]

What did I do wrong? Isn't the inverse of an angle of $0$ is just $0$, which is is also in the range of the principal argument as in the figure below?

[image]

Moreover, in another example in the textbook (same sequence but with a positive real part)
$$z_n=2+i\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}$$
the limits of the argument were both $0$ and hence it exists. What is the difference here? Why both $0$ and not, say, $\pi$, as above?

Comment: The limit exists and equals to $-2$. Why do you say it does not exist?

Comment: @science Sorry, wrong problem statement. The point is that although the limit of the sequence exists, that of the argument doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement
$$\theta_0=\tan^{-1}\Bigl(\frac{(-1)^n}{-2n^2}\Bigr)
  =-\tan^{-1}\Bigl(\frac{(-1)^n}{2n^2}\Bigr)$$
is wrong.

In the case $n$ is even, this says
$$\theta_0 =-\tan^{-1}\Bigl(\frac1{2n^2}\Bigr)\ .$$
Remember that $\tan^{-1}$ of a positive number gives an angle in the first quadrant, and so your answer is in the fourth quadrant.  However, $z_n$ has negative real part and positive imaginary part, so it is in the second quadrant, so the argument is
$$\pi-\tan^{-1}\Bigl(\frac1{2n^2}\Bigr)\ .$$

See if you can finish this off and then do the case of odd $n$ yourself.

---

For the problem you mentioned at the end of the question, $z$ has positive real part and therefore is in the first or fourth quadrant.  That's why the sort of calculations you did work out correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Using $\theta_0$ as the principal argument of $z_n$ with $-\pi < \theta_0 \leq \pi$, it seems to me that when $n$ is even, we have

$$\tan\theta_0 = \frac{\mathrm{Im }\ z}{\mathrm{Re }\ z} = \frac{-1}{2n^2}$$ so that $$\theta_0 = \pi - \tan^{-1}\frac{-1}{n^2},$$

while for odd $n$, we have

$$\theta_0 = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right) - \pi.$$

If you really want, I can provide the crude drawings that lead me to believe this, but it hinges on the fact that $\tan^{-1}\theta \in (-\pi/2, \pi/2)$, while we need the principal argument $\theta_0$ to be between $-\pi$ and $\pi$.

If you look at what your angles are converging to, you'll see $0$. But that certainly shouldn't be the case, since $z_n$ converges to a value on the negative $x$-axis, where the angle is $\pi$. That should send up a red flag.